# Will I lose my data if I update Django version?

Tags: django

So I am developing a django project in an AWS virtual env. To use a package, I need a newer version of Django, but I already have a lot of important data stored in Django's database.

My question is: Will updating the Django version mid-development compromise the data I already have in the database?

I apologize if the question seems stupid, I just really don't mess anything up.

Thanks in advance

Comment: No! you won't lose your data.

Comment: However it seems a bit strange to say you are developing on AWS. Normally you develop on your laptop and deploy to AWS.

Answer (score 0):

The database Django uses is a separate thing (e.g. PostgreSQL, MySQL...), independent from it. Django only interacts with it to write and read data.

Updating Django to a new version might break something in your code if it uses old Django features that have been removed, but it won't affect your database.

Nevertheless, it's always a good idea to backup everything before crucial updates.